# How do I save my inputted edit text and have it accessible when starting a new intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a quiz app so that when the user clicks the plus button it takes them to a page where they input the question and answer which they can then save and is taken back to the previous page where a new button with the text set to the question is created. I have all of this coded and working except for the part where I can save the previously inputted question/answer activity state if the user wants to edit it. I've been told I need to send my question and answer from my main activity to my second activity in the form of a bundle but I have no idea how to access another layouts id in my main activity (and also how to use bundles in general). Can someone please help? Here's my code:

Main Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)


        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
        }
    }
}}
```

Second Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener{
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what do you want to achive. but I am trying to seperate your question into 2 questions.

1. You want to save your inputed text, so that you can edit it latter.

**You can use Shared Preference Manager**

Sample :

```
    /*Save your values to SharedPreference*/
    // create shared Prefrence Manager
    // edit() This allows you to write key-value pairs to
    //SharedPreferences.
    val sharedPre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit()

    // add key-value pairs to SharedPreferences
    sharedPre.putString("Key","Value")

    // Instruct the SharedPreferences Editor instance to apply the changes.
    sharedPre.apply()


    /*Load your values from SharedPreference*/
    val loadSharedPre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
    
    // its return Map with string and value
    loadSharedPre.all
```

2. send my question and answer from my main activity to my second activity in the form of a bundle
   **You can use parcelable, for more details you can visi this [site](https://medium.com/the-lazy-coders-journal/easy-parcelable-in-kotlin-the-lazy-coders-way-9683122f4c00)**

Comment: Basically i want it so that when the new button is created the inputted question and answer is automatically saved so that when its opener again its still there and editable